# How to change Alternate Table Row Colors in struts

Tags: html, css, struts

i'm using `<logic:iterator>` tag to Display table data like this

```
    <logic:iterate id="LT" name="lastToken" scope="request">
        <tr>
          <td class="TblHometd"><bean:write name="LT"  property="tokennumber" format="#"/></td>
          <td class="TblHometd"><bean:write name="LT"  property="adjustmenttime" format="hh:mm:ss"/></td>
          <td class="TblHometd"><bean:write name="LT"  property="actualfinishedtime" format="hh:mm:ss"/></td>
          <td class="TblHometd"><bean:write name="LT"  property="consultationtype"/></td>
          <td class="TblHometd"><bean:write name="LT"  property="mobileno" format="#"/></td>
          <td class="TblHometd"><bean:write name="LT"  property="consultationstatus"/></td>
          <td class="TblHometd"><bean:write name="LT"  property="smsstatus"/></td>
        </tr>
   </logic:iterate>
```

now i want to change `background color for alternate rows` how can i do this ????

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this

```
    tr td{
       background:yellow
    }
   tr:nth-child(odd) td{    
      background:red
    }
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/qk2Lp/2/)**

Answer (score 2):

CSS:

```
table#LT tr:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color: #F00; 
}
```